# How to draw binary tree view using WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, binary-tree

I want to draw it like this Image :

[image]

I can draw a binary tree on console. I want to draw it using WPF. Here is my code which I write for console.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<BinaryTreeData> myBinaryData = new List<BinaryTreeData>();
        myBinaryData.Add(new BinaryTreeData{ownID=1});
        myBinaryData.Add(new BinaryTreeData { parentID=1, ownID = 2 });
        myBinaryData.Add(new BinaryTreeData {  parentID=1,ownID = 3 });

        foreach (var item in myBinaryData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}------{1}", item.parentID, item.ownID);   
        }
    }
}

class BinaryTreeData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _ownID;
    private int _parentID;

    public int ownID
    {
        get { return this._ownID; }
        set { this._ownID = value; this.onChange("ownID"); }
    }

    public int parentID
    {
        get { return this._parentID; }
        set { this._parentID = value;  this.onChange("parentID"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void onChange(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged!=null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I can`t understand how can I do that.

Comment: I think the problem is your datastructure: 
Your structure isn't a tree like structure. Sure you have IDs for reference but you don't have an implicit object structure.
Can you change your BinaryTreeData to have a Collection of BinaryTreeData to reference subItems?
If you can change this binding to a treeview via a HierarchicalDataTemplate is fairly easy then.

Answer (score 2):

Each of your tree nodes need to have a collection of children. If you want to limit it to a binary tree then you can limit your collection of children to a max capacity of 2 items.

I would recommend this tutorial as it will also show you how to achieve this with MVVM.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx

**EDIT:**

Since you have updated your post and it seems like you are looking for something different, I think you would be better off using a 3rd party solution instead of implementing your own.

Try looking at these solutions -

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/LayeredTreeDraw.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CustomTreeViewLayout.aspx

Answer (score 1):

So, I restructured your code according to my above comment.
The BinaryTreeData now have a SubItems List.
You'll have to adjust the  namespace in XAML / local:BinaryTreeData and it should work..
Cheers !

**BinaryTreeData:**

```
  public class BinaryTreeData : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private int _ownID;
    private int _parentID;

    public int ownID
    {
      get { return this._ownID; }
      set
      {
        this._ownID = value;
        this.onChange("ownID");
      }
    }

    private List<BinaryTreeData> _subitems = new List<BinaryTreeData>();

    public List<BinaryTreeData> Subitems
    {
      get { return _subitems; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void onChange(string propertyName)
    {
      if (PropertyChanged != null)
      {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
    }
  }
```

**XAML:**

```
<TreeView x:Name="myTreeView">
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BinaryTreeData}" ItemsSource="{Binding Subitems}">
      <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=ownID}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

**CodeBehind:**

```
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  List<BinaryTreeData> myBinaryData = new List<BinaryTreeData>();

  BinaryTreeData parent1 = new BinaryTreeData() { ownID = 1 };
  parent1.Subitems.Add(new BinaryTreeData { ownID = 2 });
  parent1.Subitems.Add(new BinaryTreeData { ownID = 3 });

  BinaryTreeData parent2 = new BinaryTreeData() { ownID = 4 };
  parent2.Subitems.Add(new BinaryTreeData { ownID = 5 });
  parent2.Subitems.Add(new BinaryTreeData { ownID = 6 });

  myBinaryData.Add(parent1);
  myBinaryData.Add(parent2);

  myTreeView.ItemsSource = myBinaryData;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is 100% correct but i want to make my GUI like this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/BA93U.gif

Comment: The exercise to change the HierarchicalDataTemplate to produce the desired look is not quite trivial, but you may get to it using Grids consisiting of the item and one half of the connecting line in the parent and the child. The visibility of the line could be set using a property "HasLeftChild"/"HasRightChild"...